# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi Im trying to create a stored procedure in to update a column in Oracle SQL developer. When calling the function from c# this error appears:

ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_UPDATEREFILLCHECKPLANSET'
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

What is the cause and how do i solve this problem?

The procedure below:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_UPDATEREFILLCHECKPLANSET 
(
  In_MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks"%type,
  In_DefDaysBetweenRefillChecks IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."DefaultDaysBetweenRefillChecks"%type,
  In_MasterAdjustMaxNotices IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."MasterAdjustMaxNotices"%type,
  In_DefaultDaysBetweenNotices IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."DefaultDaysBetweenNotices"%type,
  In_DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNot IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNotice"%type,
  In_SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance"%type,
  In_DefaultDaysAfterTermination IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."DefaultDaysAfterTermination"%type,
  In_EmergencyShutDown IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."EmergencyShutDown"%type,
  In_Reason IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."Reason"%type,
  In_MasterAmountOfPauses IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."MasterAmountOfPauses"%type,
  In_MaxAmountOfPauseDays IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."MaxAmountOfPauseDays"%type,
  In_Id IN NUMBER
)
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"
  SET
    "MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks" = In_MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks,
    "DefaultDaysBetweenRefillChecks" = In_DefDaysBetweenRefillChecks,
    "MasterAdjustMaxNotices" = In_MasterAdjustMaxNotices,
    "DefaultDaysBetweenNotices" = In_DefaultDaysBetweenNotices,
    "DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNotice" = In_DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNot,
    "SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance" = In_SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance,
    "DefaultDaysAfterTermination" = In_DefaultDaysAfterTermination,
    "EmergencyShutDown" = In_EmergencyShutDown,
    "Reason" = In_Reason,
    "MasterAmountOfPauses" = In_MasterAmountOfPauses,
    "MaxAmountOfPauseDays" = In_MaxAmountOfPauseDays
    WHERE "Id" = In_Id;
END SP_UPDATEREFILLCHECKPLANSET;
```

The call to the update stored procedure.

```
public void UpdateRefillCheckPlanSettings(RefillCheckPlanSettings updatedSettings)
        {
            if (_dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _dbConn.Open();
            }

            const string command = "SP_UPDATEREFILLCHECKPLANSET";

            using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(command, _dbConn))
            {
                oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                try
                {
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks", updatedSettings.MasterAdjustMaxRefillChecks);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_DefDaysBetweenRefillChecks", updatedSettings.DefaultDaysBetweenRefillChecks);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_MasterAdjustMaxNotices", updatedSettings.MasterAdjustMaxNotices);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_DefaultDaysBetweenNotices", updatedSettings.DefaultDaysBetweenNotices);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNot", updatedSettings.DaysBeforeFirstRefillCheckNotice);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance", updatedSettings.SendNoticeIfPositiveBalance);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_DefaultDaysAfterTermination", updatedSettings.DefaultDaysAfterTermination);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_EmergencyShutDown", updatedSettings.EmergencyShutDown);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_Reason", updatedSettings.Reason);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_MasterAmountOfPauses", updatedSettings.MasterAmountOfPauses);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_MaxAmountOfPauseDays", updatedSettings.MaxAmountOfPauseDays);
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_Id", updatedSettings.Id);
                    oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal("Couldn't update RefillCheckPlanSettings! RefillCheckPlanSettings: '" + updatedSettings.Id + "'", ex);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are passing MasterAdjustMaxNotices but assigning it to   "MasterAdjustMaxNotices" = In_DefaultDaysBetweenNotices,     "DefaultDaysBetweenNotices" = In_DefaultDaysBetweenNotices,  in the update statement ?

Comment: Your right but that didnt resolve the problem. I updated the questin since I altered the code. The error in the code in corrected but the old error still exists

Comment: Is this procedure standalone, or part of a package?

Comment: Can you plz specify which is the line 5? Highlight that plz .Also, check if you are initializing the values for RefillCheckPlanSettings properly.

Comment: Please add the DDL for the table in question to your question.

Comment: Can you plz specify which is the line 5? Highlight that plz .Also, check if you are initializing the values for RefillCheckPlanSettings properly.May be there is a problem with the datatypes of the values. Otherwise there seem to be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the mistake is in this parameter:

```
In_DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNot IN "Ref_RefillCheckPlanSettings"."DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNotice"%type,  
oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_DaysBefore1stRefillCheckNot", updatedSettings.DaysBeforeFirstRefillCheckNotice);
```

since the type name aren't equal:
DaysBefore**1st**RefillCheckNotice != DaysBefore**First**RefillCheckNotice